# Move file from one repository to another with history in svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, collabnet, subversion-edge

How to move a file from one repository to another repository preserving history in subversion?

- svn server 1.6v
- svn client 1.7v

Comment: Does not makes sense to me, or you have not provided all context info. For example, if you move file `a.txt` with change on `rev100` from `repo A` to `repo B` which has only 25 revisions, what would you expect to see?

Answer (score 2):

Follow-up to David's answer

With [`svnrdump dump`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnrdump.c.dump.html) you can get dump from any remote repository and for any URL inside it (which also can be URL of single file), which can be extracted to new repository with `svnadmin load` (local repo) or `svnrdump load` (remote repo)

Answer (score 1):

To move history in Subversion, you have to *dump* and *load* the repository. The [svnadmin dump](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html) will dump out a repository in a standard text-format. Then, you can use [svnadmin load](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html) to load the text-dump into another repository. These commands use pipes and redirects, so it's possible to run `svnadmin dump` directly into a `svnadmin load`. You can also use [svndumpfilter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svndumpfilter.html) to filter out the revisions you don't want.

For these commands to work, you need to be on the Subversion repository server.

Comment: don't forget about `svnsync` and `svnrdump`.